# Problem in listening to event emitted by a function in smart contract

Tags: ethers.js

If two users call this function simultaneously, then the transaction which is confirmed first will emit an event that is being shown to both users. Because of this same id is being assigned to both products.

Emmiting Event

```
 function assignProduct(string calldata name, uint quantity) public {
        productDetails memory newProduct;
        newProduct.productID = id;
        newProduct.productName = name;
        newProduct.productQuantity = quantity;
        newProduct.productOwner = msg.sender;
        IdTOProduct[id] = newProduct;
        productOwnerHistory[id].push(msg.sender);
        emit ProductAssign(id, name, quantity);
        id++;
    }
```

Listening to Event:

```
 contract.on("ProductAssign", (id, name, quantity) => {
              add(Number(id), name1, role, Iname, harvestDate, amount, contact);
              window.alert(
                `${id} assign to product ${name} having ${quantity} kg amount`
              );
            });
```